# How to popup javascript modal with code instead of button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="m_modal_1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

I have the following button that pops up the modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#m_modal_1"> Launch Modal</button>
```

Instead of initiating from the button, how do I popup from code?  I was thinking something like this:

```
if(status == 1){

    modal("show");
}
```

Comment: You could give an id to your button, hide it and trigger click event like this `$('#yourButton').click();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using Bootstrap (based on the classes).

You can use the following:

```
$('#m_modal_1').modal('show')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add eventlistener to any element, so once the event is triggered you change classes of the modal element or style.

Assuming you have some element (ie button with classname btn and modal with classname modal)

```
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.modal').classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

And your css can be like this

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
  // or
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using bootstrap. 
so in your case

```
if(status == 1){

    $("#m_modal_1").modal("show");
}
```

"show" is a option of modal function. 
See more option and usage here 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options

Answer (score 0):

Basically it depends on when you want to popup your modal.suppose you want to popup on page 
ready then,

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
$(#modal_id).show();
});
```